# If i pass a dynamic variable in URL , Css are not applying to my JSP page.

Tags: java, css, jsp, model-view-controller

In my page_controller

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/category/{id}/products")
public ModelAndView showCategoryProducts(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
 ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
 Category category = null;
 category = CategoryDAO.get(id);
 mv.addObject("title",category.getName());
 mv.addObject("category",category);
 mv.addObject("userClickCategory",true);
 return mv; 
}
```

and i checked the passed userClickCategory in my page.jsp in following way

```js
<c:if test="${userClickCategory==true}">
    <%@include file="home2.jsp"%>
   </c:if>
```

jsp page is displaying but css not applied.

[image: CSS are not applying]

Comment: You should use ajax request. `<%@include file="home2.jsp"%>` needs server compilation.

Comment: Can you say how to do it. I haven't an idea to do

Comment: How you implemented userClickCategory  in jsp?

Comment: I have attached. You can see the the second code snippet.

Comment: OK .Instead of setting this ` userClickCategory` varieble . Use tiling . for example apache tile3. There you can change your body from server itself.